# Using future simple tense in a thesis

Tags: word-usage, future

Being a non-native speaker, I have of course a bit of a problem with writing my thesis in English.
In the thesis, I propose a software solution and I describe it. What I am not sure is: should I use "going to" (as it is planned) or "will"?
Because it seems there are too many "going tos":

> The patient is going to activate the system. The system is going to
>   show a stand-by screen, which is going to disappear after 5 seconds.

Comment: Describe the solution and what it *does*-  The patient activates the system.  The system shows a stand-by screen which disappears after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, the thing is I describe the implementation - e.g. the system is going to use a database table for this etc. I describe how it is going to work (it is a plan for implementation, so not sure if present tense would be suitable)

Comment: You keep using “is going to”. Why? And no, changing it to “will” will not make any difference to my question. What @Jim has written in his comment is the cleanest approach.

Comment: I am going to go to school. I am going to going to going to go to school. *Going-to*'s are annoying colloquialism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would word it this way:

> The patient activates the system. The system will display a stand-by screen which disappears after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

> > The patient is going to activate the system. The system is going to show a stand-by screen, which is going to disappear after 5 seconds.
>
> When the patient activates the system, it will show a stand-by screen lasting five seconds.

Comment: In the revision I'd write *for*, not  *lasting*; and I'd replace *when* with *after* or *if*.  Eg,  “After the patient activates it, the system will display a stand-by screen for five seconds.”